# Stop cursor from going to start of text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, focus

I have a search function that searches for a driver from a list. When a letter is entered into the text field the list updates depending on what was entered in the text field. So if I enter `a` then it will show all drivers being with `a`.
The problem is after each letter is entered the cursor goes back to the start of the text field.

The code that runs the text field is this:

```
 table += "<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><input class=\"SearchBox\" type\"text\" id=\"txtAddressSearchOption\" onkeyup=\"SearchVehicleTypeList(this.value)\" value=\"" + SearchString + "\" onload=\"this.focus()\" /></td></tr>";
```

And the code for textAddressSearchOption is:

```
function AddressSuccess(result) {
        document.getElementById("dvAddressList").innerHTML = result;
        $('input#txtAddressSearchOption').focus();
    }
```

How to get the cursor to focus at the end of the text field?

Comment: It doesn't _"go back to the start"_, you are destroying the old node they were typing into and replacing it with an entirely new one. Try using _DOM methods_ instead of generating _HTML_.

Comment: @PaulS. can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what browser you use.

You always call $('input').focus() after overwriting the list's innerHTML, and it makes the browser reset the cursor position on the input element.

This one is better:

```
$('input').not(':focus').focus();
```

Only when it's lost focus, call focus.